# Magento 2 - product's url_key changed automatically

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls, url-key

We are using Magento 2.2.5. Currently in Magento store we managing url key by concatenating product's name with the brand's name. So many times in some products url key of product's changed from only product's name. For example,

product's name is **abc** and brand name is **xyz**, then we generating url key as **xyz-abc** and importing these keys via product import. And after import it all looks fine and working well. But after some time it's get changed automatically from url_key **xyz-abc** to **abc** (So it's brand names removed for some products). and also we have done indexing, still don't know what is issue. Also there are no 3rd party extension that causing this kind of issue.

Dose anyone know something about this?

Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: not sure, might be in some cases you won't get brand name from where you are concat it with a product name

Comment: No all product's have brand names, I have confirmed that.

Comment: Something like I have checked the url_rewrite table and somewhere l looks like url_key => xyz-abc records deleted and generating new url_key based on product's name. But it's just normal theory but don't know what causing this issue.

Comment: Try to put a logger within `Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel`'s `setData()` method on calls that `url_key` is the `$key`. This way by using `debug_backtrace()` you would be able to see from where it triggers.